# Get DNS infos for local machine interfaces

Tags: go, dns

I need the DNS suffix of all my local interfaces on my PC.

Is there way how I can achieve this via Go?

- Best case would be for any OS
- Necessary: working on Windows

I have tried `net.Inferfaces()` and all the net commands but I haven't found anything regarding the DNS server.

**EDIT**

I have found the [solution for the Windows-specific version](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.zx2c4.com/wireguard/windows/tunnel/winipcfg) but it would be interesting if there is anything that works for Linux and macOS too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a solution that work for any OS. In Linux the DNS suffix is not interface specific but system wide, it is configured in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Here is an excerpt from the man page:

```
search Search list for host-name lookup.
              By default, the search list contains one entry, the local domain name.  It is determined from the local hostname returned by gethostname(2); the local domain name is taken to be everything after the first '.'.  Finally, if the hostname does not contain a '.', the root domain is  assumed  as  the
              local domain name.

              This  may  be  changed  by listing the desired domain search path following the search keyword with spaces or tabs separating the names.  Resolver queries having fewer than ndots dots (default is 1) in them will be attempted using each component of the search path in turn until a match is found.
              For environments with multiple subdomains please read options ndots:n below to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks and unnecessary traffic for the root-dns-servers.  Note that this process may be slow and will generate a lot of network traffic if the servers for the listed domains are not local, and
              that queries will time out if no server is available for one of the domains.

              If there are multiple search directives, only the search list from the last instance is used.
```

The net package standard library [parses this file](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.3:src/net/dnsconfig_unix.go) to get the DNS config, so the DNS resolver should behave as expected, however, the parsing functionality is not exposed.

The [`libnetwork.GetSearchDomains`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/moby/libnetwork@v0.5.6/resolvconf#GetSearchDomains) func in the libnetwork library should be able to help you out. If there are no `search` entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`, you should use the hostname, which can be gotten with the [`os.Hostname`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Hostname) func.

---

I believe this also works for FreeBSD and Mac OS since they are both "UNIX like". But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: but basically i still have to code 2 seperate versions for windows and Unix right?

Or is there any ways just having 1 programm with 2 "trees" if you know what i mean

Comment: Yea, you can use [buildconstraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) to compile the correct version depending on the OS you are compiling for. Or use [runtime constants](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#pkg-constants) for dynamic checking(slower). This is also how the standard library handles differences between operating systems.